# Date check on form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with datepickers. On Submit I call `$('#form').on('submit')` to check the dates choosen in the pickers against a sharpoint list with booked dates. I have a method that retrives these dates with Ajax. My problem is when I check the dates with an IF statment in a For loop the `form.submit` gets hit even thou it shouldnt. I want to Break from the loop when the dateCheck hits a booked date. But I dont now where to put the `form.submit` so it dosent get hit by mistake. i did trie with an IF around the `form.submit` to check if an array contains any booked dates.  but no luck. Thanks for all the help in advance!!

```
if ($("#startDatePicker").datepicker("getDate") !== null) {

  if (!$("#enddate").is(":hidden") &&
    $("#endDatePicker").datepicker("getDate") === null) {

    $("#infoModal h4").text("Hint");
    $("#infoModal p").text("Please select a End date");
    $("#infoModal").modal("show");

  } else {

    var bookedDates = [];
    //ForLoop för som kollar alla datum mot valda datum
    for (var i = 0; i < parsedDates.length; i++) {

      if (dateCheck(start, end, parsedDates[i])) {
        $("#infoModal h4").text("Validation error");
        $("#infoModal p")
          .text("You have entered a busy date or interval that overlaps an already booked date.");
        $("#infoModal").modal("show");
        bookedDates.push(parsedDates[i]);
        break;

      }

      if (!$.isArray(bookedDates) || !bookedDates.length) {
        form.submit();
      }
    } //parsedDates loop

  } //endDatePicker != hidden && endDatePicker != null


} //StartDatePicker != null
```

Comment: how should we test your code? Read this: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure , but as per my understanding you want to submit the form when in bookedDates Array has some value(date) in it.
Your below condition results in TRUE when there is no date in array like

```
!$.isArray(bookedDates) -> false (As it's a array)
!bookedDates.length -> true  (if no date is push in array then value is 0 and !0 -> True and form will submit.
 if (!$.isArray(bookedDates)||!bookedDates.length) {
      form.submit();
    }
```

---

i will suggest you to put the below if condition outside the for loop.

```
 if ($.isArray(bookedDates) && bookedDates.length) {
      form.submit();
    }

$.isArray(bookedDates): it should be a array
bookedDates.length : and Must have one date inside the array.
```

Comment: Perfectly good question. I want to only submit when the array is empty. That means there are no overlaping dates to the new date range.